# Get the number of records in a huge object monthwise

Tags: apex, configuration

I need to get the record count in an object monthly. But the number of records is huge around 8 million records. I cannot put in any filters and i could not report on the object as well.

Can you suggest ways to get the record count monthly for the past three years.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this approach but think it would work. A batchable can query and process up to 50 million records.

```
public class YourBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,
        implements Database.Stateful {

    private Map<String, Integer> monthCounts = new Map<String, Integer>();

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // You could add date limits in here
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                select Id, CreatedDate
                from YourObject__c
                ]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, YourObject__c[] scope) {
        for (YourObject__c sob : scope) {
            String month = sob.CreatedDate.year() + '-' + sob.CreatedDate.month();
            Integer c = monthCounts.get(month);
            monthCounts.put(month, c != null ? c + 1 : 1);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'your email address'});
        mail.setSubject('Month Counts Result JSON');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(JSON.serializePretty(monthCounts));
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {mail});
    }
}
```

then run with the biggest available scope size:

```
Database.executeBatch(new YourBatchable(), 2000);
```

Comment: Over or up to 50M? Those two things sort of contradict each other. :P

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yep confusing phrasing on my part. Will fix.

Comment: Where does that cap come from? Is it in the limits page? Ah I see it: *Maximum number of records returned for a Batch Apex query in Database.QueryLocator - 50 million* It's even in the [google summary](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=apex%20governor%20limits). :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson From [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Comment: I wonder if analytic snapshots would work here; simply get counts by date (grouped by calendar month) I've never had a database this large to test on - you would be well under the 2000 row limit per snapshot.

Comment: @cropredy I'd be interested in learning about it so think you should post it as an answer with a bit more detail if you think it will work...

Answer (score 2):

While I have never tried this on 8 MM records, have you considered Analytic Snapshots?

1. Create a summary report on `theObject` summarizing by `createdDate`, grouping dates by calendar month
2. Schedule the report to run monthly, data is output to a custom object
3. The first run of the snapshot should use a report filter that goes back 3 years
4. The subsequent runs should use a report filter that goes back just one month (since, you are using created date, no need to requery)
5. In the event that the snapshot times out, run multiple snapshots for each quarter (12 for the past three years)

You'll end up with a custom object containing counts of records (and anything else you can summarize by month) that can be the source for dashboards

Answer (score 1):

CreatedDate is always going to be an indexed field, so you can filter by that. Whether or not that will be enough will depend on your data, but it could be.

You need answers for 12x3=36 months, so you can just do a separate query for each month.

```
DateTime threeYearsAgo = DateTime.now().addYears(-3);
DateTime startMonth = DateTime.newInstance(threeYearsAgo.year(), threeYearsAgo.month(), 1);
List<Integer> results = new List<Integer>();

while(startMonth < DateTime.now()) {
    DateTime endMonth = startMonth.addMonths(1);
    results.add([SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate >= :startMonth AND CreatedDate < :endMonth]);
    startMonth = endMonth;
}

System.debug(results);
```

Since you still have some headroom before you hit 100 queries, you could make the interval even smaller and do more queries if any of those return too many results to handle